# HTML React set caret to different contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable

I have implemented a project in which there are some *contenteditable* divs.

When the enter key is pressed within the middle of the text of one of these divs, I split the div into two separate *contenteditable* divs, but the caret goes to the beginning of the first div when React re-renders the components.

I am wondering if there is any way to make the caret go to the beginning of the second div, which would make the interface feel much more natural.

I know the id of both divs, if that helps.

Comment: Focus in react is typically handled using `refs`. [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: Okay, I will check it out. Thank you @TravisM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using `refs` to focus that I pulled from the react docs.

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={this.textInput} />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.focusTextInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! I actually ended up using this instead, just because it was easier for the way my project was implemented, since I knew the id of the components. `document.getElementById(<id>).focus();`